# How to get the path of android installed application

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am new to Android and I want to know that how can we get the path of the installed application in android, So that we can open the file in our application by using that installed application.

for example:
I want to open the pdf file or doc file in my application but i require the path of that application which can open this file...

Please Help me 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see why you need this path... intents are made for this.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about that the intents can made this all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I used the Following Code to do this**

```
private void openFile(File f)

    {

        // Create an Intent

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        // Category where the App should be searched


        // String category = new String("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        // Setting up the data and the type for the intent

        String type = getMIMEType(f);
        /*Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/*");*/
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), type);

        // will start the activtiy found by android or show a dialog to select one

        startActivity(intent);//


        /**intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK+Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        String theMIMEcategory = getMIMEcategory(type);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f),theMIMEcategory);
        try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Applicaton"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
         //show error
        }
         */
    }

    /**

     * Returns the MIME type for the given file.
     *
     * @param f the file for which you want to determine the MIME type
     * @return the detected MIME type
     */
    private String getMIMEType(File f)
    {

        String end = f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1, f.getName().length()).toLowerCase();

        String type = "";

        if(end.equals("mp3") || end.equals("aac") || end.equals("aac") || end.equals("amr") || end.equals("mpeg") || end.equals("mp4")) type = "audio/*";

        else if(end.equals("jpg") || end.equals("gif") || end.equals("png") || end.equals("jpeg")) type = "image/*";

        else if(end.equals("pdf")) type = "application/pdf";

        else if(end.equals("xls")) type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        else if(end.equals("doc")) type = "application/msword";

        else if(end.equals("zip")) type="application/zip";
        else {type="*/*" ;}



        //type += "/*";

        return type;

    }

    public static String getMIMEcategory(String aMIMEtype) {
        if (aMIMEtype!=null) {
            aMIMEtype = aMIMEtype.substring(0,aMIMEtype.lastIndexOf("/",aMIMEtype.length()-1))+"/*";
        } else {
            aMIMEtype = "*/*";
        }
        return aMIMEtype;
    }'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how things work in Android. To call another installed application, you'll have to do it with an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Android will then select the application(s) best suited for what you're trying to do, and use them to open the file you need. In your example, the code would be something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open PDF"));
```

Look at the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) javadoc to have more explanations about that (the `createChooser` part is here to allow the user to choose between various apps if more than one can open the designated file)